# Does the YouTube JS API work in non-Flash environments?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api

At the present time (Nov 2013), the docs for YouTube's JS API state:

> **Requirements**
>
> The end user must have Flash Player 10.1 or higher installed to view
>   everything correctly. Because of this requirement, we suggest using
>   SWFObject to embed the SWF and detect the user's Flash Player version.

See  https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference.

Should I use the JS API or just avoid it in favor of native browser methods?

Comment: This JS API interfaces with Flash. The version issue is not in JavaScript but in Flash. I see no reason not to use the JS API.

Comment: @frits Generally Flash doesn't work on mobile devices, and works poorly on anything other than Windows.

Answer (score 0):

YouTube offers an HTML5 player but you can't force it at this time.

Only viewers themselves can indicate they would like the HTML5 player instead of the Flash player. I think the APIs are set up to work with both the Flash variant and the HTML5 variant.

So, yes, YouTube works in non-Flash environments, but only under certain conditions.

Comment: "I think the APIs are set up to work with both the Flash variant and the HTML5 variant." Do you have a reference for that? So far the only info I have is the quote in my question that says the JS API is Flash only.

Comment: Just try it? Set your viewing mode to HTML5, see if the video loads in HTML5, see if your code still works.